# Plotting discrete time signals involving sumations in matlab.

Tags: functions, summation, graphing-functions, matlab, signal-processing

Many of the examples I've encountered while looking for an answer are simple functions that do not involve summations.

Suppose I have the following function;

```
f(n) = sum(n*cos(n-k)) from k=-infinity to infinity
```

How would I go about making the discrete plot in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

```
f = 0;
n = linspace(-6*pi, 6*pi, 5000);     
k = -100;

for i = -k:k
    f = f + n*cos(n - i);
end

plot(n, f)
stem(n, f)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't completely answer my question. Perhaps you might modify it to address the "X must be same length as Y" error I receive when I attempt a stem plot, i.e; stem(n,f)

Comment: The question was about *discrete* plot. A small change that could be made: `plot(n,f,'+')` (or another symbol).

Comment: @pyler it works just fine when I do stem(n,f). I had a type.  It said for k =-k:k when it should have been i=-k:k and cos(n-i).